# assistance with C# loop

Tags: c#, loops

I just completed this code and would like to change the following code to a loop. Each department has a specific button that they are supose to click and should be visible only to those who are within either dept 1, 2, or 3.

Can someone give me some kind of guidence here.

```
                pchk.Visible = true;

                Int32 count = 0;
         count = chk.GetCount(1);
         // dept 1
                if (count == -1)
                {
                    btnDept1.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnDept1.Text = "Next dep1[" + count.ToString() + "]";
                    if (count == 0)
                        btnDept1.Enabled = false;
                }

                // dept 2
                count = chk.GetCount(2);
                if (count == -1)
                {
                    btnDept2.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnDept2.Text = "Next dep2 [" + count.ToString() + "]";
                    if (count == 0)
                        btnDept02.Enabled = false;
                }
                // dept 3
                count = chk.GetCount(3);
                if (count == -1)
                {
                    btnDept3.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnDept3.Text = "Next dept3 [" + count.ToString() + "]";
                    if (count == 0)
                        btnDept3.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Probably need to begin by putting the buttons in a list so you can loop over them.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, and wouldn't even compile if you had included it all. (You refer to `btnDept2` and `btnDept02` in the `if (count == -1)` branch, for instance. If you want to get help here, post **real, compilable code**. Posting made up on the spot code often hides the actual problem, and it almost always wastes people's time (the people you're asking for free help, BTW).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        count = chk.GetCount(i);
        if (count == -1)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    btnDept1.Visible = false;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    btnDept2.Visible = false;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    btnDept3.Visible = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch(i)
            {
                case 1:
                    btnDept1.Text = "Next dep1[" + count.ToString() + "]";
                    if (count == 0)
                        btnDept1.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    btnDept1.Text = "Next dep1[" + count.ToString() + "]";
                    if (count == 0)
                        btnDept1.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    btnDept1.Text = "Next dep1[" + count.ToString() + "]";
                    if (count == 0)
                        btnDept1.Enabled = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not incrementing the "button" each iteration like he requires. btnDept1, btnDept2...etc

Comment: Your code does nothing about changing `btnDept` for each number in the loop.

Comment: Maybe do something like Button[] buttons = new [btnDept1, btnDept2, btnDept3];  buttons[count].Text = blah blah;

Answer (score 3):

The biggest challenge with converting this to a loop is getting the `btnDept1` values based on a numeric value.  One way would be to introduce a method which does this with a switch statement

```
Button GetButton(int id) {
  switch (id) {
    case 1: return btnDept1;
    case 2: return btnDept2;
    ...
  }
}
```

Or another approach would be to keep them in an array and use the index to access the array.  Either way once you have that you can collapse to a loop in the following way

```
for (int i = 0; i < TheCount; i++) {
  int id = i + 1;
  Button button = GetButton(id);
  int count = chk.GetCount(2);
  if (count == -1) { 
    button.Visible = false;
  } else { 
    button.Text = String.Format("Next dep{0} [{1}]", id, count);
    if (count == 0) {
      button.Enabled = false;
    }
  }                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private void SetButton(int id, Button btn)
{
    var count = chk.GetCount(id);
    if (count == -1)
    {
        btn.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        btn.Text = String.Format("Next dep{0}[{1}]", id.ToString(), count.ToString());
        if (count == 0)
            btn.Enabled = false;
    }

}
```

Usage can be something like this:

```
SetButton(1, btnDept1);
SetButton(2, btnDept2);
SetButton(3, btnDept3);
```

Of course, if you use an array / list of buttons it can be even easier...

e.g.

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[] { btnDept1, btnDept2, btnDept3};
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
   SetButton(i, buttons[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier, way to get the button you want. Simply append the `i` value to "`btnDept`" in `ActiveForm.Controls[...]`. Check for null, and go to work...

```
    for (int i = 0; i < deptCount; i++)
    {
        Button b = ActiveForm.Controls["btnDept" + i.ToString()] as Button;

        if (b != null)
        {
            if (count == -1)
            {
                b.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // etc.
            }
        }
    }
```